# classList in Haskell Help

Tags: haskell

Can anyone help with my last assignment question that i got stuck on for 2 days straight.
I'm suck at Haskell and this question seems to be too advanced for me, so please help me cos its due mid-night tonight.

Any help is really appreciated.

Here is my question.

Your main task in this question is to define the function
`classlist :: (Codes, Marks) -> Ranks`
that takes the list of names and id numbers, and the list of id numbers and
marks, and returns the list of names, marks, and final rankings.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are `Codes`, `Marks`, and `Ranks` already defined in the assignment?

Comment: What do you have so far?  It would be easier to help you if you showed us what you have accomplished (or not accomplished) in the past two days.

Comment: At least some folks around here are willing to give _specific_ help to someone doing homework, but if you're looking for someone to _do_ your homework, I'd suggest looking elsewhere. And if you're not expecting someone to _do_ your homework, then you should spell out what you've tried, what hasn't worked, etc. and try to ask specific questions.

Comment: Also, it appears that you have only given part of the spec - You say "main task", but do not even mention the other tasks.  Also, you need to define `Codes`, `Marks`, and `Ranks` as Jacob already mentioned.  Finally, grammatical and typographic (id vs. ID) errors in the phrase *"Ranks that takes[sic] the list of names and id[sic] numbers, and ..."*  indicate that you have paraphrased the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts: (1) get name and mark matched together, then (2) rank the names by their marks.

For the first part of your question, you should think something like this:

`Codes` maps a `Name` to an `Iden`. `Marks` maps a `Iden` to a `Mark`. Somehow you have to map a `Name` to a `Mark`.

To do that, for each `Name` in `Code`, take the associated `Iden` and look it up in `Marks`. That should give you the associated `Mark, which you can then match with the`Name`.

For the second part, you have to sort the newly associated `(Name, Mark)` pairs, probably by `Mark`. Then you should be able to take that list and add a `Rank` to each one, starting from 1 and counting up.

By the way, midnight is still 4 hours off for me, but I bet that it is considerably closer for you (unless you are in Australia)...so this advice may not come in time. You might start asking your instructor or classmates for help earlier next time.